# C++ nesting function with pointer as return value

Tags: c++, function, pointers, copy, nested

I have a class containing a pointer

```
template<Foo> class Class{
    Foo * ptr;
public:
    //constructors, assignment
    Foo* view(){return ptr;}
}
```

and function taking `Foo*`as an argument

```
double fn(Foo*){ /*Implementation*/ }
```

Does the implementation

```
Class C;
fn(C.view());
```

cause the class member `ptr` to bee copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the *pointer* is passed by value, i.e. it's copied. Maybe twice, depending on optimizations. What it *points to* is not copied.

Comment: Couldn't have said it any better.